# AngularJS style not working on a new enviornment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I am in serious need of your you.

My application is working on an old environment, then I moved the same source code to a new environment.  It seems (guessing) to me that the stylesheet and images couldn't be loaded on the new environment even though the source code is the same.

Any suggestion and help are highly appreciated.

Some notes,

- i. the old working environment is NodeJs 6.11, Angular2 and
  Angular-cli 1.0.0
- ii. the new not-working environment is NodeJs 8.4, Angular4 and
  Angular-cli 1.4.3
- iii. I put the bootstrap on local
  "app/css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Expected first page with style and logo. This is still working on the old env:
[image]

I got the plain mark-up below on the new environment. All the styles and images are gone. The firefox console on the right hand side showed that those are not loaded. Will it related to the new version of Webpack?
[image]

My code - app.component.html
[image]

My new not-working package.json
[image: Package.json]

My index.html
[image: index.html which load the css]

Please kindly help. I am a beginner on HTML and AngularJS.
Please kindly let me know if I need to provide more information or I need to upgrade some modules.

Best regards,
Autorun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your css styles, images and javascript files inside the assets folder in the latest version of angular-cli.

use your images like below from assets folder :

```
<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="assets/iamges/logo.png">
```

And add your stylesheet and javascript file inside the .angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  <!-- "assets/css/style.css" from assets folder -->
  <!-- "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" from node modules -->
  "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  <!-- "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" from node modules js files -->,
  <!-- "../src/assets/js/javascript.js" from inside assets files-->
],
```

After changes restart your porject.

Comment: Hi Chandru, thx for your quick help. It works! I got you idea, but I didn't move my css and images to the asset folder. I specified my existing folder app/css and app/images in the angular-cli.json. It works.       "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "app/css",
        "app/images"
      ],

Answer (score 0):

This is to continue on Chandru's answer. It works. Please see the screenshot of my change. Since I can't post screenshot in comment, I hope it is ok to post here.

[image]